# how to create jcombobox with jcheck box and multiple selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist, jcheckbox

I want to create JComboBox with checkboxes and multiple selection . i have created a list with check box after rendering the jlist . I dont know how to render it with jcombobox . Or is it possible to make jlist as drop down list like combo box . 
 for jlist rendering i am using the following code

```
  DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    ListCheckBox li= new ListCheckBox(listModel);
    JScrollPane jsp= new JScrollPane(li);
    add(jsp);

    listModel.add(0,new JCheckBox("Other Court"));

    listModel.add(0,new JCheckBox("Tribunal Court"));

    listModel.add(0,new JCheckBox("High Court"));
   listModel.add(0,new JCheckBox("Supreme Court"));
```

ListCheck Box class is as following

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.border.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ListCheckBox extends JList
{
protected static Border noFocusBorder =
 new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);

public ListCheckBox(DefaultListModel model)


  {

   super(model)  ;
   setCellRenderer(new CellRenderer());

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
     {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
           int index = locationToIndex(e.getPoint());

           if (index != -1) {
              JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox)
                          getModel().getElementAt(index);



              checkbox.setSelected(
                                 !checkbox.isSelected());
              repaint();
            }
          }
        }
      );

     setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
   }

   protected class CellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer
   {
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
    JList list, Object value, int index,
    boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
     {  JCheckBox checkbox = (JCheckBox) value;
     checkbox.setBackground(isSelected ?
      getSelectionBackground() : getBackground());
     checkbox.setForeground(isSelected ?
     getSelectionForeground() : getForeground());
     checkbox.setEnabled(isEnabled());
     checkbox.setFont(getFont());
     checkbox.setFocusPainted(false);
     checkbox.setBorderPainted(true);
     checkbox.setBorder(isSelected ?
      UIManager.getBorder(
       "List.focusCellHighlightBorder") : noFocusBorder);
      return checkbox;
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'll be awaiting an comment to your question -> never to put JComponents for Renderers in Swing, did you tried to use Renderer with Boolean value as demonstrated Oracles JTables tutorial, not to easy job to create an Editable JComboBox that react to right_mouse_event???(maybe) for Editor in JComboBox, JList by default never to nest Editable Objects, use JTable with one column without JTableHeader instead, really no idea how to solve that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to create a popup menu with a `JCheckBoxMenuItem` for each option, and then attach that popup menu to a button that displays whatever you would want to show for the "selected item".

```
final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Other Court"));
menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Tribunal Court"));
menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("High Court"));
menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Supreme Court"));

final JButton button = new JButton();
button.setAction(new AbstractAction("Court") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        menu.show(button, 0, button.getHeight());
    }
});

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(button);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: this hides the combobox on a single item  selection but i want it should stop till the user doesnt click on combo box again

Comment: You can do this by just [reopening the menu](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/) when one of the items is clicked on.