# SWING - Multiple JCheckBox in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, jcheckbox

I've a JTable where each cell from a column to contain a list of JCheckBox (to select multiple skills from the list)
Any idea how to do that or an alternate way?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it have to be done within a single cell...or could it be done across multiple columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a JPanel (and add desired amount of JCheckboxes to the panel) as the TableCellRenderer.

Or you can create a TableCellRenderer based on JTable (e.g. 1 column with checkboxes in rows)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'd need something like this [combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/MultiComboBox/ScreenShot.gif). The user should be able to select multiple values in a 16 items list.

[edit] I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787379/how-to-create-jcombobox-with-jcheck-box-and-multiple-selection)